# How to create NSImage from pixel array in Xcode for macOS app

Tags: objective-c, nsimage

Developing apps for iOS, it is simple to extract pixels from `UIImage`, manipulate them, then reconstruct an `UIImage` from them, example:

```
csr = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(pax, devlar, devalt, 8, devlar*4, 
      csr,kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast);
rim = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
gen = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:rim scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];*
```

But developing a macOS app, things are different, data structures and methods are different, and I don't understand how to.

Answer (score 1):

The process is exactly the same except rather than `UIImage` convenience initializer [`imageWithCGImage:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624124-imagewithcgimage/), you call `NSImage` initializer [`initWithCGImage:size:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage/1519939-initwithcgimage?language=objc):

```objectivec
NSImage *image;
CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

if (cgImage) {
    NSSize size = NSMakeSize(width, height);
    image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage size:size];

    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
}
```